# AIR 2 - Data Persistence?

Tags: air, persistence, preferences, store

what is the best way to include data persistence in an AIR 2 application?

is it creating your own read/write file with flash.filesystem, or is there a new way with AIR 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that adobe wrote a library for saving preferences in AIR years ago, but have never added it to the official library?  now i'm curious why they would not have done so, since data persistance is key for desktop applications.

adobe's AIR Preferences library ("as3preferenceslib"), consisting of 3 classes, can be found on Google Code [here](http://code.google.com/p/as3preferenceslib/source/browse/trunk/src/com/adobe/air/preferences/?r=10).  i've created a .SWC using these files and added them to my AIR 2  library.

a class written by Jonnie Spratley showing how to use adobe's as3preferenceslib can be found [here](http://snipplr.com/view/9288/saving-preferences-in-air/).

Comment: if you use the as3preferenceslib you'll want to correct a few grave errors that are included.